# While Sharing to facebook,Share preview is not available

Tags: facebook, share, preview

In our application, we are using facebook share functionality to share posts, articles to Facebook. Currently, facebook share preview is not available.In some cases, wrong images are showing while sharing

While sharing to facebook the share popup contains wrong image,sometimes nothing displayed.

here I'm using facebook share_open_graph property to share the post to facebook, but the og:image property is not replacing properly

```
Code Samples

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId            : '498695457184189',
        status           : true,
        cookie           : true,
        version          : 'v2.10'                
    });


    $(document).on('click' , '#fbShare' ,  function(){

        var ids = $(this).attr('id');

        var id = ids.split('-');
        var url = "{{url('wds_article_view', {slug: article.slug})}}";
        var image = 'https://www.agrideo.com/uploads/articles/{{article.coverPhoto}}';

        FB.ui({
            method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'og.shares',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                object : {
                    'og:url':url,
                    'og:title':'{{article.title}}',
                    /*'og:description': '{{article.content|excerpt(100)}}',*/
                    'og:description': '{{article.title}}',
                    'og:image': image
                }
            })
        }, function(response){
                addNotification();
            });
    });
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

While debugging using Facebook Sharing Debugger,I got this error

The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: Facebook has removed the possibility to specify any of these properties at share time a while ago, and using the `share_open_graph` method was the last remaining workaround - which they now apparently have removed as well. Your server must return all the necessary values via OG meta tags when the URL you share gets requested, that is the only way.

Comment: Can you please share  an example  how to  return all the necessary values via OG meta tags when the URL share gets requested

Comment: Your server needs to return a document that contains the necessary OG meta tags. I don’t know what kind of “example” you’d want for that …

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Open Graph Protocol site](https://ogp.me/).

Here's a rock-solid and super-plain example they provide:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

So, for your case, when you're sharing, set `og:title` to your title, `og:image` to your image, etc., etc..  There are many properties.  See what is useful for you.

***Open Graph Protocol is fun!*** *Who wouldn't want to learn this?*